# Android Background Task Freezes UI Thread - Updating Firebase

Tags: android, android-asynctask, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some code in onCreate() which is freezing the UI thread. I've tried putting it every different way I can find of to make it execute in the background. Only thing I can think of is that I have other firebase event listeners in the main UI thread, so even though the code is executing in the background, the other listeners are freezing the activity while the background updates. Or maybe my code is not really getting to the background?? Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
  AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //tried it here
    }
});
```

////////

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //tried it here
    }
 });

thread.start();
```

/////

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //tried it here
    }
};
AsyncTask.execute(runnable);
```

/// here is the code. I am trying it this way at the moment.

```
 Thread custListLoadThread = new Thread(runnable);
    custListLoadThread.start();


}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        mSelectedPlayerRef.child(mSelectedPlayer.getUsername()).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);

        final ArrayList<String> mEnteredPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

        mEntriesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot entries: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Player player = entries.getValue(Player.class);
                    mEnteredPlayers.add(player.getUsername());

                    Player draftedPlayer = entries.getValue(Player.class);
                    mEntriesRef.child(draftedPlayer.getUsername()).child("VS")
                            .child(mSelectedPlayer.getUsername()).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);

                }
                for(String enteredPlayer: mEnteredPlayers){



                    mSelectedPlayerRef.child(enteredPlayer).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    }
};
```

All of these are freezing the UI thread.

Comment: Have you checked with like https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html what hangs in the main thread? I'm not sure how firebase works but I suspect it's designed not to freeze your app. The `onDataChange` callback can possibly run in the main thread and if your code in there freezes you may have to start a thread in the callback.

Comment: the method trace is new for me. It looks like it could be useful in this situation, but I will have to play around with it and try to figure out how it works.

Comment: The listener callbacks always run on the main thread.  Adding the listener on a worker thread doesn't change that.

Comment: so that is my problem. The code takes too long to execute and it cannot be moved to a background thread because it involves a listener.

Comment: qbix, this helped. I moved the worker thread inside the listener to contain only the two for loops, which made my app responsive. If you want to write up an answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: actually, not out of the woods yet, but your comment put me on the right track.

Comment: @ithinkthereforeIprogr'am' could you please write the answer for this problem. Im also been struck with the same problem. I would be helpful for needy.

Comment: did anyone find a solution for this.
I have the same problem.

Comment: I think Bob Snyders comment helped me on this one, the listener callback always runs on the main thread no matter what so you may need to restructure your code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but this is how I would do it:
`

```
    final ArrayList<String> mEnteredPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

    mEntriesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                for(DataSnapshot entries: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Player player = entries.getValue(Player.class);
                    mEnteredPlayers.add(player.getUsername());

                    Player draftedPlayer = entries.getValue(Player.class);
                    mEntriesRef.child(draftedPlayer.getUsername()).child("VS").child(mSelectedPlayer.getUsername()).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);

                }
                for(String enteredPlayer: mEnteredPlayers){
                    mSelectedPlayerRef.child(enteredPlayer).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try removing the thread and run your code in the OnCreate method....like this

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    mSelectedPlayerRef.child(mSelectedPlayer.getUsername()).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);

    final ArrayList<String> mEnteredPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

    mEntriesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot entries: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Player player = entries.getValue(Player.class);
                mEnteredPlayers.add(player.getUsername());

                Player draftedPlayer = entries.getValue(Player.class);
                mEntriesRef.child(draftedPlayer.getUsername()).child("VS")
                        .child(mSelectedPlayer.getUsername()).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);

            }
            for(String enteredPlayer: mEnteredPlayers){



                mSelectedPlayerRef.child(enteredPlayer).setValue(mEmptyResultsItems);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
```

}

Comment: thanks for the reply. I originally tried it in onCreate and it froze the thread which is exactly why I'm trying to move it to the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler:

```
protected static Handler sHandler = new Handler();
```

Use the Runnable you have created as is.

Then instead of:

```
Thread custListLoadThread = new Thread(runnable);
custListLoadThread.start();
```

use:

```
sHandler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No luck. To me it seems like any of these should work

Comment: By no luck do you mean the code does not execute or do you mean it does execute but also blocks the UI Thread?